# pyspark v 1.6 dataframe no left anti join?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

perhaps I'm totally misunderstanding things, but basically have 2 dfs, and I wan't to get all the rows in df1 that are not in df2, and I thought this is what a left anti join would do, which apparently isn't supported in pyspark v1.6?

```
df1:

+----+---+
| id | x |
+----+---+
| 1  | a |
| 2  | b |
| 3  | c |
| 4  | d |
+----+---+

df2:

+----+---+
| id | x |
+----+---+
| 1  | a |
| 2  | b |
+----+---+

desired output df3:

+----+---+
| id | x |
+----+---+
| 3  | c |
| 4  | d |
+----+---+
```

I'm trying:

```
df3 = df1.where(~col("id").isin(df2["id"]))
```

which gives me .count() of 0 rows

and:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on = ["id"], how = "leftanti")
```

for this I get the following exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u"Unsupported join type 'leftanti'. Supported join types include: 'inner', 'outer', 'full', 'fullouter', 'leftouter', 'left', 'rightouter', 'right', 'leftsemi'."
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can mimic **`leftanti`** join with **`left join`** and filter only null columns from id in `df2`.

**`Example:`**

```
df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"),col("a.id") == col("b.id"),"left").filter("b.id is null").select("a.*").show()
#+---+---+
#| id|  x|
#+---+---+
#|  3|  c|
#|  4|  d|
#+---+---+
```

Starting from Spark2.4+ we can use [**`exceptAll`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll) function for this case:

```
df1.exceptAll(df2).show()

#+---+---+
#| id|  x|
#+---+---+
#|  3|  c|
#|  4|  d|
#+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed the answer of @Shu for Spark 1.6 (which unluckily is still used in a lot of legacy systems) and I generalized it for futher use, if anybody will ever need it:

```
def subtractByKey(df1, df2, key):
    return (df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"), on=F.col("a.{key}".format(key=key)) == F.col("b.{key}".format(key=key)), how="left")
            .where("b.{key} IS NULL".format(key=key))
            ).select("a.*")
```

Same behaviour may also be reached in more recent Spark version also with

`df1.join(df2, on=key, how="left_anti")`